# How do I make a flex element bigger with padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div, and I'm trying to have the padding on top and bottom be a little bit more, to distance the text from the edge. The div I'm talking about is the parent one (#skip). The CSS is as follows:

I tried using padding and margin, but both don't have the intended effect. Any suggestions?

```css
.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
}

.subtext {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

#skip {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  top: 470px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 55px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #9f9f9f;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #A8C8A3;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="skip" style="height: 5vh;padding-top: ;" class="position-absolute">Entra
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="subtext">Home Page Classica</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.subtext {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: auto;
}

#skip {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  top: 470px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 505px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #9f9f9f;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #A8C8A3;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="skip" class="position-absolute">Entra
  <div class="subtext">Home Page Classica</div>
</div>
```

Try This!

Update:

Don't make the `width: auto;` Then you can do your padding

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Don't make us compare line-by-line to figure out what you did.

Comment: Had to see line by line, but it's wrong, I'd tried this as well and the mid div ("break") gets bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the styling in your html
2. clean up your code, delete duplicates.
3. add a wrapper, so you can center the div vertically and horizontally on the  page (I assumed that was your goal)
4. define a width for the #skip element
5. add padding, remove eventually line-height

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}


#wrapper {
  display        : flex;
  align-items    : center; /* align vertical */
  justify-content: center;  /* align horizontal */
  height         : 100%;
}

#skip {
  flex-direction     : column;
  padding            : 60px 30px;
  min-width          : 30%;
  border-radius      : 100px;
  background         : #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow         : 0 4px 4px #9f9f9f;
  color              : #A8C8A3;
  text-align         : center;
  text-transform     : uppercase;
  font-size          : 60px;
  font-family        : 'Lato', sans-serif;
  /* line-height        : 28px; */
  cursor             : pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.break {
}

.subtext {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="skip" class="position-absolute">Entra
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="subtext">Home Page Classica</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had removed some of the code just to clear things up a little.

The cleanest way to move the text away from the edge is actually to use padding, but as you found, it annoyingly changes the width of our parent element. We can negate that effect by adding the `box-sizing: border-box` property to the element we will be applying the padding to. This way, the padding actually gets put onto the inside of the element, rather than the outside.

In my code snippet below, I gave the parent `#skip` the `display: flex` property, along with the `flex-direction: column`, `justify-content: center`, and `align-items: center`. When centering items in a column flex, `justify-content` aligns them vertically, while `align-items` aligns them horizontally.

In order to space everything out, I went ahead and added a margin to the `.subtext` element as well.

The reason there were so many issues with spacing on yours, is because you were collapsing the parent by assigning the `#skip` element a height that would have been smaller than the resulting height from the `font-size` you had set.

In terms of responsiveness, it is generally best practice to let the elements base their height on the content of the element.

You should also refrain from defining line-heights in pixels, try to use `em` or `rem`'s instead. They adjust based on the font-size of the parent element.

```css
.subtext {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

#skip {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 32px;
  
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #9f9f9f;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #A8C8A3;
}
```

```html
<div id="skip">
  Entra
  <div class="subtext">Home Page Classica</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be fine, but the position needs to be absolute so that it floats and doesn't move the other elements.